# To get a trigger or notification to angular whenever GCP bucket got upadted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, angular8

I wanted to get a notification to angular when gcp bucket got updated .Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

Comment: Thanks but webapp2 package doesn't work properly in python3.

Comment: The link I provided explains the technical details. You will need to write your own code. The examples make for a good start.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with John, please check the Watching a bucket part.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is: whenever a bucket is updated a http post request is sent to your python web application. All you need in python is to handle this post request.

For example

```
import http.server
import socketserver
from http import HTTPStatus


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello world')
        
    def post(self):  
        if 'X-Goog-Resource-State' in self.request.headers:
          resource_state = self.request.headers['X-Goog-Resource-State']
          if resource_state == 'sync':
            logging.info('Sync message received.')
          else:
            an_object = json.loads(self.request.body)
            bucket = an_object['bucket']
            object_name = an_object['name']
            logging.info('%s/%s %s', bucket, object_name, resource_state)
        else:
          logging.info("Other post.")    


httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', 8093), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

After the web server above is up, then, in Cloud Console redirect notifications to your URL

```
gsutil notification watchbucket yourULR gs://BucketName
```

The def post(self) is coppied from webapp2 example here

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

Web server code is copied from here

https://gist.github.com/davidbgk/b10113c3779b8388e96e6d0c44e03a74